# Allow viewing edit history when reviewing suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review, revisions-list

Sometimes when reviewing edits you come across crazy stuff.

[image]

"What the heck happened here?" you might ask yourself. I wanted to see if an intermediate edit got nuked, but the revision history link just took me back to the review screen.